# Переход на импортирование модулей

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Возникла необходимость подключить модуль однако на клиенте запрещено использовать require. Поскольку смешивать require и import нельзя решил во всём проекте заменить импорты. Получаю ошибки множественные ошибки, не могу понять что делаю не так. Есть 2 файла:

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import * as router from './router.js';
const app = express();
app.use(router); // тут падает ошибка, описание в конце
```

**router.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (_request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/html/index.html`);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Ошибка следующая:

> TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Вопрос: как нужно правильно экспортировать и импортировать файлы, функции?

**Дополнение**

файл **cookies.js**

```
export function setCookie(name, value, options = {}) {
   // ...
}
export function getCookie(request, name) {
   // ...
}
```

На сервере работает `getCookie`, к нему вопросов нет. На клиенте нужен setCookie, подключаю его через html:

```
<script type="module" src="/js/cookies/cookies.js" defer></script>
```

Подключен также файл скрипта для страницы:

```
<script src="/js/cookies/home.js" defer></script>
```

Саму функцию вызываю из `home.js` используя `setCookie('USER', result[0].id, false)`. Пишет об ошибке

> ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined

Как тогда нужно подключать файл с клиента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import express from 'express';
import {router} from './router.js';

const app = express();
app.use(router); // если middleware правильно написали, ошибки быть не должно
```

```js
import express from 'express';

export const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (_request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/html/index.html`);
});
```

Comment: А если есть скрипт, который подключается и к серверу и к клиенту, как подключать и вызывать такой файл на клиенте? У меня файл для работы с куки, я ко всем функциям дописал export, но на клиенте, он пишет что функция не определена.

Comment: Если бы вы показали код - было бы проще понять что у вас не так, со слов не очень понятно.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: `ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined` - говорит о том что функция не обьявлена, и судя по всему вы забыли ее импортировать, добавьте в `home.js` импорт `setCookie`

Comment: Я так пробовал, но тогда возникает `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` и функции объявленные в файле обозначаются как не объявленные.

Comment: в тех скриптах где используются модули добавьте их в html с  `<script type="module" src="some/path.js">  <script/>`

Comment: Уже установлено, не помогло